# getting git colors in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, git

I have just installed XCode and [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/). I have successfully run "GitHub->Install  Command Line Utility". I can connect to repositories with both apps and I can use the git command in the terminal.

However the git command does not use any colors (as I am used to just like in the below screenshot).

What can I do to get colors (preferably directly in OSX termianl, but an extra console would  do too).

[image: git in colored console]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git config --global color.branch auto
git config --global color.diff auto
git config --global color.status auto
git config --global color.ui auto
```

The global configuration is saved to `~/.gitconfig`, which you can also edit directly with a text editor.

Refer to the manual of [`git-config`](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xF-zpNnhK1cJ:www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html&hl=en) for more options.

Comment: Strange, on Windows I did not have to do this.

Comment: @bitbonk: The msysGit package comes with a system-wide configuration file which enables colors automatically.

Comment: How can I find out where I got git from? I guess it can only be the GitHub app or XCode

Comment: XCode 4 supports git natively: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#version-editor

Comment: I only bothered with the last line (`color.ui auto`) and it colors everything for me now. I don't think you need the rest.

Comment: Link is broken :/